# Visual studio compile files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

It is possible to compile files of the same project using both `UNICODE` and `MULTI-BYTE`? I think i read somewhere that you can do this by using `#ifndef` guards, but i am not sure if it's true as i was not paying too much attention.
I ask this because i have a project with `unicode` set and i copied some files that are written with `non-unicode`.

```
CString m_strWork1 = "some text";
Write(LPCTSTR(m_strWork1), m_strWork1.GetLength());
```

For this example i get this error: `cannot convert parameter 1 from 'LPCTSTR' to 'const char *`

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle if someone wants to edit the code :) http://jsfiddle.net/UYpw5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mix `CStringW` (Unicode) and `CStringA` (multibyte) in the same code, without any problem:

```
CStringA m_strWork1 = "some text";
Write(LPCSTR(m_strWork1), m_strWork1.GetLength());
```

Comment: Using `CStringA` throws this error: `cannot convert from 'CStringA' to 'LPCTSTR'`

Comment: It's `LPCSTR` in my code, not `LPCTSTR`. Pay attention to the differences: `LPCTSTR` (tchar, #ifdef dependent) vs `LPCWSTR` (Unicode, #ifdef independent) vs `LPCSTR` (multibyte, #ifdef independent)

Comment: Also be aware that `sizeof(wchar_t)` is 2 while `sizeof(TCHAR)` is #ifdef dependent, so when the number of bytes (allocations, file writings) is for `LPCTSTR` `GetLength() * sizeof(TCHAR)`.